# SQLite-NET Универсальный метод

Tags: sqlite, request

Доброго времени суток, коллеги!
Помогите в создании универсального метода для посылки запроса в бд SQLite-net (android)

Есть база:

```
public static SQLiteConnection Connect
    {
        get
        {
            var file = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/base.db";
            if (!File.Exists(file)) CreateBase(file);
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection(file, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite, false);
            return conn;
        }
    }
```

Пытаюсь сделать универсальный метод так:

```
public static TableQuery<T> Find<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr)
    {
        return Connect.Table<T>().Where(expr);
    }
```

выдает ошибку - Connect.Table 'T' должен быть неабстактным типом и иметь открытый конструктор без параметров (все это у класса есть)

хочу добиться чтобы обращение к функции имело вид:

```
var ret  = sqlite.Find<user>( user => user.id>5 ); // пример
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(Func<T, bool> expr) where T : new()
    {
        return Connect.Table<T>().Where(expr);
    }
```